# Defining Phantom Types - can't compile examples

Tags: haskell, types, algebraic-data-types, phantom-types

I'm trying to learn more about Phantom Types. I'm trying to read through [Fun with Phantom Types](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/ralf.hinze/publications/With.pdf) by Ralf Hinze. He's using a keyword `with` I haven't seen before and that I can't get to compile. I get a parse error on `=` when I try this.

```
data Type t = RInt                    with t = Int
            | RChar                   with t = Char
            | RList (Type a)          with t = [a ]
            | RPair (Type a) (Type b) with t = (a, b)
```

Earlier in the paper, he says that the "with" statements aren't strictly necessary, that you can set `a = t` instead, but I can't figure out how to define this data type without them. The following errors with: `Not in scope: type variable 'a'`

```
data Type t = RInt
            | RChar
            | RList (Type a)
            | RPair (Type a) (Type b)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like it's very possible to write the above using GADTs, but I'm still interested in what Ralf intended. Is there a special keyword with? Can you express this without GADTs?

Comment: > "If only we had the means to constrain the type argument of Term to a certain
type. Now, this is exactly what the aforementioned ‘mild’ extension allows us to
do. Given this extension we declare the Term data type as follows..." Maybe I missred but I think this is a *imagined* extension that does not really exist (or so **I** think) but yeah GADTs will do ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that the definition sans-`with` suggested in the paper is

```
data Type t = RInt
            | RChar
            | RList (Type t)
            | RPair (Type t) (Type t)
```

Above, the parameter `t` is never used. It is, indeed, phantom.

This implies that, e.g.

```
RInt :: Type a
```

for *any* type `a`. By contrast, if the `with` constraints were followed, it would be impossible to have `RInt :: Type t` for any t but for `t ~ Int`.

The `with` syntax is not present in GHC, but GADTs play essentially the same role.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
data Type t where
   RInt  :: t ~ Int   => Type t
   RChar :: t ~ Char  => Type t
   RList :: t ~ [a]   => Type a -> Type t
   RPair :: t ~ (a,b) => Type a -> Type b -> Type t
```

Note how `with` is replaced by an equality constraint in each constructor. It's basically the same thing, written differently.

More compactly, we can rewrite the above into

```
data Type t where
   RInt  :: Type Int
   RChar :: Type Char
   RList :: Type a -> Type [a]
   RPair :: Type a -> Type b -> Type (a,b)
```

where the constraints have been "inlined" in the final type.

Answer (score 8):

Although ugly, the following will work and might be considered slightly closer to that notation in spirit. This is essentially desugaring a GADT into type equalities (which seem not to have their own extension so you need *either* `GADTs` or `TypeFamilies` enabled to use them) and existentials.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification, TypeFamilies #-}

data Type t = t ~ Int => RInt
            | t ~ Char => RChar
            | forall a. t ~ [a] => RList (Type a)
            | forall a b. t ~ (a, b) => RPair (Type a) (Type b)
```